# ars_progress_dialog and ars dialog are DISCONTINUED flutter packages. Name the alternatives

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to use ars_progress_dialog but it is discontinued
Customizable progress dialog for Flutter applications with smooth animation for background dim color and blur.

The next option is ars_dialog 1.0.8 but apparently its discontinued. Which flutter packages can be used to replace the package.

Comment: check out [simple_circular_progress_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_circular_progress_bar) package.
Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to implement the answer in your main dart:

```
// Example 16
SimpleCircularProgressBar(
    mergeMode: true,
    onGetText: (double value) {
        return Text('${value.toInt()}%');
    },
),
```